# Dissecting each part of payloads step by step with Scapy

Tags: python, scapy

I'm wondering how to dissecting payload according to differents fields type / length using Scapy.

For example, I have this =>

```
|###[ Raw ]###
        |   |  load='\x00!\x92(\x00!\x92(\x00\x00\x01\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xc0\xa8\x03\x01\xc0\xa8\x03\x02\x01\xc0\x00\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x18\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

I would like to divide each part step by step: the first part in 2 bytes / the second part in 4 bytes etc...

Actually, I added a new protocol using Scapy but the last part is very complex to manage, so thats why I choose/try to dissect the last part of payload in this way (above).

Answer (score 2):

The best way to dissect complicated protocols in Scapy is by understanding all of the available fields (which can be difficult given its poor documentation).

A list of fields supported in Scapy: http://trac.secdev.org/scapy/wiki/Fields

In particular look at the ConditionalField:

```
ConditionalField(XShortField("chksum",None),lambda pkt:pkt.chksumpresent==1)
```

Also, learn how guess_payload_class() can be used to select different layers during Scapy dissection.  If you want to dissect it in small sections (2 bytes/4 bytes etc) consider creating a layer for each section and using guess_payload_class(). http://trac.secdev.org/scapy/wiki/BuildAndDissect

If you have a more specific question on how to dissect certain fields, I can try to answer it, but for now that is the best advice I can give for your general question.  Hope it helps.